# Can not persist the deletion of a record using Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am using Core Data in a simple table view app which keeps track of a user's exercises. When one record is deleted, the deletion persists across that launch of the app. However, if I close the app and re-open it, the record re-appears. The user can delete the record from a detail view:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
{
    //delete record from database...
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Parameters" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@", parameters.name];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData) {
        [context deleteObject:obj];

    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
{

}
}
```

I can not figure out why the deleted record re-appears. This occurs on the simulator and on the device. I 'reset content and settings' on the simulator but still no luck.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Context is a "scratch pad". The "scratch pad" concept allows you to made changes locally in that "scratch pad", such as modifying the record or deleting the record, and discard the changes if you decide too.

You can also have multiple contexts or "scratch pads", usually one context in each thread, such as one for main thread, and another one for background thread.

Now, if you have decided that the changes are OK, you need to persist the changes by saving the context.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error];
```

Of course, if you have other "scratch pads" in your app, you will need to sync those changes you have saved in the core data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `save:` method after you're finished doing changes to your Managed Object Models

Hope this helps!